# Airflow use the external sensor to wait the end of a DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I would like to use a sensor to make a DAG wait for another DAG before starting.

I produced the following code to do so :

```
ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='task_that_wait_the_dag_before_starting',
        external_dag_id='dag_to_wait_it_finishes',
        dag=dag

    ) >> TaskToExecute(
        task_id='task_to_execute,
        dag=dag)
```

But when I deployed it, I have the error :

> Broken DAG: Argument ['external_task_id'] is required

This is an argument for the external task.
The thing is I don't want to wait for a particular task, I want to wait for the dag to entirely.

In the doc we can see this :

> Waits for a different DAG or a task in a different DAG to complete for a
>       specific execution_date

Why is the external_task id is required if I can just wait for a DAG.

Comment: Try to just add  `external_task_id=None` like `ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='task_that_wait_the_dag_before_starting',
        external_dag_id='dag_to_wait_it_finishes', external_task_id=None, 
        dag=dag)`

Comment: it didn't seem to work the first time I tried. Will try again.

Comment: Is there any progress? I would be very glad to understand how is possible to implement it.